# Is it possible to remove boilerplate code related to parameterized constructor inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a web application  that has many controllers. Thus I created a base class called `BaseController` and I added a parameterized constructor to it for the purpose of DI (Dependency injection).

```
 public BaseController(IConfiguration configuratin)
```

Now when I want to inherit from this based controller, C# complains that I need to create a parameterized constructor in my derived class too, even though I have nothing to add to it.

This become redundant and since I have too many controllers, this boilerplate code is not efficient for me.

Is there a way to not write this? I'm open to design changes too.

Comment: There is no constructor inheritance. Each class has to define its own constructors. Might be a good use case for [Source Generators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/) if/when you can move to C# 9.

Comment: Also refactoring tools (like Resharper) can usually generate all such constructors for you in child class with a single click.

Comment: There are other forms of DI, e.g. property injection. But I wouldn't call single line `public Inherited(IConfiguration configuration): base(configuration) { ... } ` "not efficient" or redudant. Too many classes is the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Damien_the_Unbeliever, there is no constructor inheritance in c#.

If there is simple one or a few parameters for the base class it is simple enough to just add a constructor, and refactoring tools can do this for you.

If there are a lot of parameters there are a few options you might consider:

1. Put all the dependencies of the base class in a parameter object that is added to the DI container. So only one object has to be forwarded to the base class.
2. Make your parameter object contain all the logic that you want to share. So the base class of your controllers would just forward calls to this object. The advantage of this is that if you need a new dependency for some new feature, there is a greater chance that the change will be limited to one class.
3. Avoid a base class altogether, use [composition instead of inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)